# Conflict between two origins of coordinate in eso-pic

Tags: positioning, eso-pic

Two watermark prints need to be put at different places of the same page. One at lower left corner, the other at page center. To do this, macros `\AtPageLowerLeft` and `\AtAtPageCenter` from package `eso-pic` are used.
I want to set the origin of coordinate in accordance with conditions. So another macro `\position` is introduced by `\let`. But this causes the former watermark print at a wrong place, please see the code for details:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\begin{document}
\null
\let\position\AtPageCenter
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
        \position{%
            \put(0,0){paper center waterprint}
        }
    }
%
\let\position\AtPageLowerLeft
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
        \position{%
            \put(20,20){lower left waterprint}
        }
    }   
\end{document}
```

You can see that both watermark prints are located at lower left corner of the page.

[image]

Can anyone tell me the reason?

Comment: The text is inserted at **shipout**, when the page is written, at this time \position has the second meaning. Btw: Edit your question and correct some of the errors, "Marcos" instead of "macros" looks quite odd.

Comment: So, is there a solution to block \position from changing until the former waterprint is finished?

Comment: I don't know as I don't understand what you are trying to achieve and why you can't simply write `\AtPageCenter` and `\AtPageLowerLeft` instead of `\position`.

Comment: I need to construct a marco in which the position of origin of coordinate is a argument,for example, \mywaterpint{ll} will typeset a waterprint based on the lower left corner of the page, and \mywaterpint{pc} will typeset a waterprint based on the pape center. If I call \mywaterprint{pc}, then \mywaterprint{ll} at the same page, both waterprints are located on the lower left corner of the page. So, could you help me with this problem? Thank you.

Comment: With your last comment, this seems to be a [xy-problem](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean). Please edit your question to ask what you want (and what have been answered by Ulrike).

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question in the comment. You can can e.g. do something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\makeatletter
\let\mypackage@esopicposition@pc\AtPageCenter
\newcommand\mypackage@waterprint@pc{\put(0,0){paper center waterprint}}

\let\mypackage@esopicposition@ll\AtPageLowerLeft
\newcommand\mypackage@waterprint@ll{\put(20,20){paper left waterprint}}


\newcommand\mywaterprint[1]{%
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
        \csname mypackage@esopicposition@#1\endcsname {%
            \csname mypackage@waterprint@#1\endcsname 
        }
    }}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\null
\mywaterprint{pc}

\mywaterprint{ll}
\end{document}
```

As you are so allergic against an @ in a command name here a version without them:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic}


\let\mypackageXesopicpositionXpc\AtPageCenter
\newcommand\mypackageXwaterprintXpc{\put(0,0){paper center waterprint}}

\let\mypackageXesopicpositionXll\AtPageLowerLeft
\newcommand\mypackageXwaterprintXll{\put(20,20){paper left waterprint}}


\newcommand\mywaterprint[1]{%
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
        \csname mypackageXesopicpositionX#1\endcsname {%
            \csname mypackageXwaterprintX#1\endcsname
        }
    }}


\begin{document}
\null
\mywaterprint{pc}

\mywaterprint{ll}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your solution. And, is the mechanism "makeatletter...\makeatother" mandatory, I mean, can I have a version of Latex without this mechanism?

Comment: Sure you can. But that you can't use a @ in the internal command names.

Comment: Can I understand your soluntion like this: changing my marco name "\positon" with a internal command(use @, like \@position) will prevent from being set to the second meaning while the second call of  it occurs? If no internal commands are used, how to achieve the function I want by pure Latex? Thank you

Comment: If you don't like the @ then replace the `mypackage@esopicposition@pc` by `mypackageXesopicpositionXpc`. It doesn't matter. The @ is nothing special, only a very mild protection against overwriting.

Comment: Thank you. But if I "replace the mypackage@esopicposition@pc by mypackageXesopicpositionXpc", what's the difference between "\let\mypackageXesopicpositionXpc\AtPageCenter" and my "\let\position\AtPageCenter"?

Comment: The pc at the end (the other command has ll). This makes it possible to use different commands in the \AddToShipoutPicture. The `\csname mypackage@esopicposition@#1\endcsname` picks up the argument #1.

Comment: I think I understand your idea. Really thanks for your valuable help!!

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\myWaterprint[1][C]{%
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
      \ifx#1C
        \AtPageCenter{\put(0,0){paper center waterprint}}%
      \else
        \AtPageLowerLeft{\put(20,20){lower left waterprint}}%   
      \fi}}    
\begin{document}
\null
\myWaterprint% default is [C]

\myWaterprint[L]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a good cue to my question. Thank you!!